# RecyclerView убивается в ScrollView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-scrollview

При попытке поместить `RecyclerView` внутри `ScrollView` получаем коллапс первого. Теоретически можно внутри адаптера сделать метод `getView()`, чтобы его получить и измерить и на основе него  в коде принудительно установить высоту для `RecyclerView`, я так делал для `ListView`. Но в данном сслучае есть такая проблема - все поля в `CardView` надо отображать полностью, и высота у них может быть разная, а `MEASURE_UNSPECIFIED` возвращает высоту стандартную для данной разметки (например для TextView это высота одной строки, так как в разметке он однострочный, а в реальном использовании этот же TextView заполняется пользовательским комментарием, который может содержать сколько угодно строк, потому и высота разная. А Измерение все арвно будет, как и у одной строки). Есть ещё какие либо способы развернуть `RecyclerView` в `ScrollView`? От `ScrollView` уйти не получается, потому что на странице достаточно много информации и иначе она не помещается в экран.

Кстати параллельный вопрос, в приложении AliExpress явно используется `RecyclerView`, причем карточки там заполнены разным образом и помещены в список. То есть явно разработчик их помещал туда либо каким то извращённым адаптером, либо как то ещё. Возник вопрос, можно ли создавать CardView или наследоваться от него, и создавать Карту по аналогии с фрагментом? А потом создавать разметку непосредственно с конкретными `CardView` внутри `RecyclerView`

Comment: Та же проблема, что и с ListView: скорллируемый элемент в скорллируемом элементе, в android не работает. Можно попробовать недоавно появившийся NestedScrollView, но лучше все пихать в RecyclerView адаптером с несколькоими типами View. Проблемы с CardView я не понял.

Comment: Ммм.. Как сформулировать получше..?Есть recycler_item с cardview, в нем например textview. В адаптере создаем viewholder, в onbind назначаем текст для textview, например item + " " + position. Так происходит обычно. Вьюшка биндится одна и та же, а вслучае, который я упомянул (AliExpres) список состоит из разных разметок, то есть адаптер в зависимости от позиции подвязывает в список разные сardview. Каким образом такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4):

Нашел решение на английском стаке, переопределяем LayoutManager:

```
public class CommentLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public CommentLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }
        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Код выше не всегда хорошо работает. В случае если вы хотите чтобы элементы тоже были `wrap_content`, т.к. он измеряет ширину и высоты с `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`, лучше использовать вот это:

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {


        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {

            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    heightSpec,
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    widthSpec,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    recycler.bindViewToPosition(view, position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}
}
```