# Android RecyclerView внутри ScrollView

Tags: android, recyclerview, scrollview

Макет состоит из большой формы и RecyclerView, который при прокрутке подгружает элементы. 
Если я RecyclerView вставляю внутри ScrollView

```
<ScrollView>
<RecyclerView>
</RecyclerView>
</ScrollView>
```

то RecyclerView прокручивается только один раз и больше данные не загружаются (видны только первые 10 объявлений)

Если я ScrollView убираю, то верхнее меню вообще не прокручивается, а прокручивается только RecyclerView с подгрузкой объявлений.
Пример[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для пользователей такой вариант будет совсем не удобен.
Вопрос в том как сделать так, чтобы прокручивалась вся "страница" целиком, а не только нижняя часть (RecyclerView)?
P.S. Перепробовал много вариантов, но ни какого эффекта.

Comment: RecyclerView вставлять в ScrollView очень плохая идея, попробуйте реализовать логику перемещений с помощью CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Это не только плохая идея, но это так же и плохой опыт пользователя, если вы хотите что бы у вас осталась примерно та же структура, то стоило бы вам подумать о смещении (например просто анимацией) верхнеёй части в кнопочку или что то подобное. А иначе вы вполне можете нарваться на множество гневных отзывов о неудобности интерфейса. По поводу прокрутки, определяйте место нажатия и вызывайте его слушатель скролинга. У Вас скорее всего RecyclerView перехватывает управление. А вообще не плохо бы разметку и место реализации/использования данного экрана в студию

Comment: Вот ему спасибо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14197/lsillarionov. Та же проблема, что и с ListView: скорллируемый элемент в скорллируемом элементе, в android не работает. Можно попробовать недоавно появившийся NestedScrollView. Вот здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445063/238266